# How to force Android Studio to use a newer version of library instead of old version from another module?

Tags: android-studio-2.2

I am stuck with a strange problem. I have an android studio project which contains the main module and another library module which is the facebook sdk. The library module uses an android-suport v4 library, which is an old version. I want to use a newer version of andorid support v4 library for my main module. But Android Studio by default picks up the facebook sdk v4 library during compilation, even when i define it as a dependency in my module build.gradle. As much as this seems to be an incorrect behaviour from Android Studio how can I tell AS to pick my new library instead of the old facebook one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the library module gets its dependencies resolved first, so you have the android-support library from that module first via transitive dependency (See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:transitive_dependency_management ). A possible solution to that, is to tell gradle to exclude specific transitive dependencies, so only the one that you mention explicitly in your gradle build will be resolved and picked. See  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies on guidelines on how to do that.